# Java start Next loop iteration after inner class has finished

Tags: java, android, for-loop

So I got stuck on a pretty basic Java thing.

Namely I have an `iteration` that needs to go to a next loop after the `inner class` has finished. But since the `inner class` takes a lot of time and the `variables` that can be accessed in `inner class` must be `final` it throws me `RejectedExecutionException`.

```
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task android.os.AsyncTask$3@290074 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@d50b99d[Running, pool size = 17, active threads = 17, queued tasks = 128, completed tasks = 42]
```

Here is the simplified solution that threw the exception.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10;i++) {

        String[] cmd = { "-i",  imageToBeFiltered.toString(), "-filter_complex", filters[loopCounter], imageWithFilter.toString()};

        ffmpeg.execute(cmd, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String message) {
                super.onSuccess(message);

                //Continue loop only if it has reached onSuccess or onFailure

            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(String message) {
                super.onFailure(message);
                //Continue loop only if it has reached onSuccess or onFailure
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When doing the normal `fori-loop` it does not always wait for all of the `terminal calls` to finish and just goes on.

Comment: ffmpeg.execute is creating a new thread in the pool for each iteration and you seem to be running out of threads too. Do your calculation on an `AsyncTask` for example or use a Thread `Executor` to limit your pool, etc. It’s not really clear what you’re asking or … rather what you’ve actually tried.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini Well I tried showing what I am asking for by showing what I have done, Is it more understandable this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered recursion?

```
void myMethod(int index) {
    String[] cmd = { "-i",  imageToBeFiltered.toString(), "-filter_complex", filters[loopCounter], imageWithFilter.toString()};

    ffmpeg.execute(cmd, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String message) {
            super.onSuccess(message);

            if (index < 10) myMethod(index++);

        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(String message) {
            super.onFailure(message);

            if (index < 10) myMethod(index++);
        }
    });
}
```

EDIT:

I'm guessing that `loopCounter` is supposed to be the index, in which case you'll want to change that if you use this code.

Comment: This actually worked as I needed it to work, thank you.