# Waiting inside loop for the method to finish executing

Tags: java, android

I have a For loop in which I call a method to upload images to the server , the problem that i am facing that at a certain limit the server will force stop the opened socket so i have to upload every image at once

```
for (int i = 0; i < paths.size(); i++) {
    transferData(paths.get(i), i);
}
```

and the transferData Function I am using the transfer Utility aws s3 function

```
TransferUtility transferUtility =
            TransferUtility.builder()
                    .context(this)
                    .awsConfiguration(AWSMobileClient.getInstance().getConfiguration())
                    .s3Client(amazonS3Client)
                    .defaultBucket("name")
                    .build();

TransferObserver uploadObserver = transferUtility.upload("name", name, new File(path), CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);
    uploadObserver.setTransferListener(new TransferListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(int id, TransferState state) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onStateChanged: " + id + ", " + state);
            if (TransferState.COMPLETED == state) {
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(int id, long bytesCurrent, long bytesTotal) {
            float percentDonef = ((float) bytesCurrent / (float) bytesTotal) * 100;
            int percentage = (int) percentDonef;            
            Log.d(TAG, "onProgressChanged: " + percentage);                        
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(int id, Exception ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error during upload: " + id, ex);
            try {
                showToast(ex.getMessage());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    });
```

How to wait for the method to finish execution then continue the loop

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java start Next loop iteration after inner class has finished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52284083/java-start-next-loop-iteration-after-inner-class-has-finished)

Comment: @TheWanderer I think it is sort of duplicate but I want the loop not to increment till the function finishes whether success or fail

Comment: That's exactly what recursion will get you.

Comment: @TheWanderer I will try it using While Loop and see the result

Comment: You can look at https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/issues/291

Comment: @algrid that was very helpful thanks

Answer (score 1):

to wait loop use this code :

```
CountDownLatch latch=new CountDownLatch(1);

for (int i = 0; i < paths.size(); i++) {
    transferData(paths.get(i), i);
    try {
            latch.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}
```

and put this at the end of your method that finished upload image or failed

```
latch.countDown();
```

when your method rich to `latch.countDown();` your loop will be continue 
notice that you must put your loop in another thread except main thread